# "FOR UPDATE NOWAIT", Oracle, springframework, QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, spring, oracle, sql-update

I'm using implementing the interface that extends from `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` and `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor`

The problem I hava a query `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` with param `org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param`

I have this Query..

```
@Query(value = " SELECT c FROM Ctype c WHERE c.code = :code"
        + " FOR UPDATE nowait ")
Ctype findOneByCodeNoWait(
        @Param("code") String code);
```

I have this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.company.persistence.entity.Ctype org.company.persist.repository.CtypeRepository.findOneByCodeNoWait(java.lang.String)!
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: FOR near line 1, column 111 [ SELECT c FROM org.company.persistence.entity.Ctype c WHERE c.code = :code FOR UPDATE nowait ]
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: FOR near line 1, column 111 [ SELECT c FROM org.company.persistence.entity.Ctype c WHERE c.code = :code FOR UPDATE nowait ]\"}}"
```

I was checking another post, but they uses `EntityManager`...

How solve this?

Comment: This seems to be the Hibernate way to do it http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-locking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

`@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
 @QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout",value = "0"))
 @Query(value = " SELECT c FROM Ctype c WHERE c.code = :code")`

I have tested this with my ongoing project and this code:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
@QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout",value = "0"))
@Query("select t from Event t left join fetch t.details ")
List<Event> findAllWithDetails();
```

`

generates sql like:

`SELECT event0_.event_id ...
FROM   EVENTS event0_ 
       left outer join event_details details1_ 
                    ON event0_.event_id = details1_.event_id 
FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`

Comment: thank youn for your time to answer, another question to be sure... waht is qualified Class/Interfaces?  `import ?.?.?.Lock;`, `import ?.?.?.LockModeType;`, `import ?.?.?.QueryHints;`... Thank you in Advance...

Comment: another question How to check the generate SQL?

Comment: `import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Lock;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.QueryHints;
import javax.persistence.LockModeType;
import javax.persistence.QueryHint;`

Comment: to see generated sql add into your application.properties

spring.jpa.show-sql=true